# Unable to install Mac OS Lion on vmware

Tags: macos, osx-lion, vmware

I tried to install Mac OS on Vmware (8.0 and 7.1) and I got this error:

"Mac OS X is not supported with software virtualization. To run Mac OS X you need a host on which VMware Workstation supports hardware virtualization. "

I tried searching on google and some people said I needed to go to BIOS and enable Virtualization. I went there, but I didn't see Virtualization in BIOS.

I used Intel Processor ID Utility tool check CPU and see that:

Intel(R) virtualization Technologies is -> NO.

Is there any way I can install Mac OS on my PC?.
I need it to learn iPhone Programing...
Thanks!

Comment: It sounds as if the Intel chip in your machine does not have the hardware virtualisation instructions.  It's annoying as Intel only included the instructions in some of their chips (and not all of them like AMD).  You're out of luck, I'm afraid, as the software seems to require the hardware instructions. FYI, you're also breaking Apple's EULA.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you break the EULA and install custom kernel extensions, no. You have to buy a Mac. That's the deal with Apple.

See http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macosx107.pdf

It mentions 'Mac Computers' and 'Apple-branded computers' only.